# How can I make a pivot table in R

Tags: r, pivot

I'm a student, and I have a file for which I am learning to code. I want to make a pivot table based on my data, but I am getting an error.

My code:

```
Table=Master %>% 
  group_by(Principal.Name,Region) %>% 
  summarise(
    Total_Call=sum(`Call Count`)
  ) %>% 
  spread(Region,Total_Call)
```

The error is:

> Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : object 'Region' not found.

However, `Region` is there in my data set.

Comment: Please provide an indication of what the Master object looks like.

Comment: Are you sure `Region` is there in your data set? R is case-sensitive. Check with `str(Master)`.

Comment: Best guess: you loaded `plyr` after `dplyr`, ignored the warning, and you are inadvertently using `plyr::summarize` which doesn't know to keep the `group_by` columns around, instead of `dplyr::summarize` which is made to work with `group_by`. Change `summarise` to `dplyr::summarise` and in the future try not to load `plyr` after `dplyr`. It may be some package you loaded that loaded `plyr` as a dependency, though that is getting rare... (That, or it's a typo and there is no `Region` in your data.)